# how to restore database in phpmyadmin using files from old wamp/bin/mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I forgot to export db from phpmyadmin, but i have access to old wamp directory.

To restore db I only need to move files from wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.xx.x\data to new directory?

(old wamp is 32 bit, new is 64bit)

Comment: Did you uninstall the old version of WAMPServer?

Comment: no, but can't run old windows with old wamp. I can only move files from there via Linux. (old Windows is broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so as its WAMPServer, you can have more than one version of MYSQL installed so this should work for you.

> Stop WAMPServer

Copy `\oldwamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.xx.x` and all its sub directories into `newwamp\bin\mysql` so you should now have 2 folders under the \wamp\bin\mysql` folder like this

```
newwamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.xx.x
newwamp\bin\mysql\mysqly.yy.y
```

> Start WAMPServer

Now using the wampmanager menus do this to activate the old version of MYSQL

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> Version -> x.xx.xx
```

Now you can run your export using phpMyAdmin against your old data. Put the exports somewhere safe

Now activate the new version of MYSQL

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> Version -> y.yy.yy
```

Now you can IMPORT your EXPORTS to the new version of MYSQL

If you like you could now delete the old `newwamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.xx.x` folder and restart WAMPServer and that version will disappear.

Or you can leave it there, just in case you ever want to use it or re-do the exports

> NOTE: Only export your databases and not any you did not create yourself, or you will mess the new version of MYSQL up.
>
> For future viewers of this post. This will only work if you have a complete and undamaged old mysql folder i.e `mysql.x.xx.xx` folder and all its subfolders.

Comment: You are genius! (got some error SQL syntax while importing db, but it has nothing to do with main issue). Thank You.

Comment: Upgrade the phpMyAdmin. Some of the phpMyAdmin versions lately had some little hiccups in them. Download the latest phpMyAdmin ADDON from here http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/